# Close ticket system not working... Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, ticket-system

Hello I am having a bit of an issue with my Discord ticketing system and it is making me really confused... It does not work when it creates the channel of the ticketing system and it is really confusing me...

code:

```
Open ticket command:
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket',
    description: "opens a ticket",
    execute(message, args){
        const user = message.author.id;
        const name = "ticket-" + user;
        if(message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name == name)){
            message.channel.send("You have already opened a ticket!")
        }else{
    message.guild.channels.create(name).then((chan)=>{
    chan.updateOverwrite(message.guild.roles.everyone, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false
    })
    chan.updateOverwrite(user,{
        SEND_MESSAGES: true,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true
    })
    message.channel.send("I have created a ticket for you! Please go to the channel at the top of the server, Only you will have access to it and it will be called ticket(id)");
    chan.send("Support will be here shortly").then((m)=>{
        m.pin()
    })
    })   

     }
    }
}

close ticket command (this is were the error is):

const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'endticket',
    description: "ends the ticket",
    execute(client, message, args){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("Only a moderator can end a ticket!")

        if(message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) message.channnel.delete()
    }
}

console error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
```

I dont understand what is going wrong...
thank you.

Comment: Typo, `message.channnel` should be `message.channel` with double "n"

Comment: OOOHHHHH thnx lol